# Issues while installing swirl on R 3.4.4, Linux Mint Sonya

Tags: r, linux, linux-mint, rcurl, swirl

I tried installing swirl on my system from the R studio, and got the following error:

[Swirl installation error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C68cM.png) 
[image]

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/dipti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/dipti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘swirl’
* removing ‘/home/dipti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/swirl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swirl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpbp61si/downloaded_packages’
```

> library(swirl)
>   Error in library(swirl) : there is no package called ‘swirl’

And then I searched the internet for possible solutions, so I tried following the steps from this link:

https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/wiki/Installing-swirl-on-Linux

There were some issues while installing libcurl, but seems fine when I did this the last time.

[Libcurl installation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avFEx.png)
[image]

I retried installing swirl from the R studio, but still, the error is same.

I also tried installing dependencies like `stringi, openssl and httr`. And only `stringi` was successfully installed, both the remaining others had the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your question and state/include clearly what errors you're having? [This is me after reading your post :)](https://media.giphy.com/media/BmmfETghGOPrW/giphy.gif)

Comment: Hahaha, I'd attached the screenshot, so didn't feel necessary to include the errors. They're there now, could you suggest something?

Comment: Try this first `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` in your Mint terminal. Then in R, install.packages("swirl", dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: Yes, that worked!! Thank you! :D

Comment: You're welcome! Can you post it as an answer to help future readers? Thx

Comment: Yeah, sure. I will!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after running:

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

on the Mint terminal. Then in R,

`install.packages("swirl", dependencies = TRUE)`